# Python function with empty list parameter

Tags: python, list, function

I came across this function where an empty list is passed in as a parameter in the function.

```
def myFunction(value, values=[]):
    values.append(value)
    return values

myFunction(1)
myFunction(2)
myFunction(3)
```

The output is:

```
[1,2,3]
```

instead of:

```
[3]
```

Does this only work for lists? When I tried doing it with just an integer, it does not work.

```
def myNumber(value, values = 10):
    if value > 100:
        values += 2
        return values
        
myNumber(101)
myNumber(102)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157373/python-mutable-default-argument-why

Comment: This happens for all mutable values, so notably lists, dicts, sets and objects you define.